# If a checkbox is checked how to set a dropdown as a required field in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

In the ASP.NET MVC 3.5 app. I have a check box, "Food/Bev", which is of a boolean type, and  I'd like to know how to manage this:

If the check box is checked:

- A dropdown list `Caterer` becomes a required field.
- A request cannot be submitted unless the `Caterer` option is selected from the list.

If the check box is not checked:

- The `Caterer` dropdown list is not a required field.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Looking at your question, i wonder if you're not forgetting to check for the page's validity on postback. You should check for  if(Page.IsValid) before doing anything server-side.

Comment: @Greg - Just do a simple if condition or make use of the conditional operator to check if the checkbox is checked `chkFoodOrBev.Checked` (that returns true or false `&&` and you have a value selected in the drop down `myCaterer.SelectedIndex==-1` if both of these yield true, do not allow submitting the form (in addition, throw up an error message or alert saying so).

Comment: I added this condition to the controller, but it's not working
'if (request.FoodBeverage == true && request.Caterer == null)
                        ModelState.AddModelError("Caterer", "Caterer field is required if you serve Food & Bev");'

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @JonH Is there something wrong in the 'if condition' that I used? When I submit the form it doesn't show an error message...

Comment: @Greg - Can you put a breakpoint in and look at it through debug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a required field validator for the DropDown, and set Enabled="false" by default. Add an OnCheckChanged event to the CheckBox with AutoPostBack="true", and in the event handler set the enabled state of the validator to the checked state of the CheckBox.

Comment: Since it's a asp.net mvc web application, not a web form, I set up a dropdown list as a required on condition that if a checkbox == true, then it should be required, like
<select name="Caterer", "required = {Model.Request.FoodBeverage.value == 'true'}">
But nothing happens anyway. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I'm not to sure about this, but can you do this: {Model.Request.FoodBeverage.Checked == true}?

Comment: I changed it to "Checked", but it doesn't turn the dropdown list to a required field anyway.
In the Model I have this validation that works when a user hits a "Submit" button:
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Caterer)
                && (FoodBeverage == true))
                yield return new RuleViolation("Caterer", "Please provide a Caterer info");
Is it possible that a dropdown list gets a focus or turns to a required field as soon as a user checks a checkbox, so it should be filled before the "Submit" button gets hit.

Or at least a user gets a pop-up reminder to select a caterer.

Answer (score 2):

Just do a simple if condition

```
if this.checkbox.checked && this.mydropdown.selectedindex=-1
  //code / alert that warns the user you must make a selection
```

You can probably use the `?:` operator:

```
bool b = ((myCheck.Checked && myDropDown.SelectedIndex==-1) ? true : false);

if(b) {
 //stop submit of form as no selection was made
}
```

Or keep the code short and simple:

```
 bool b = this.CheckBox1.Checked && this.DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == -1;
 //when the checkbox is not check Response.Write(b); prints false
//when the checkbox IS checked and no item is selected, Response.Write(b); prints true
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `RequiredFieldValidator` for the drop down list, but set it to `Enabled=false`. Then, when the checkbox is checked, call the `ValidatorEnable` function to enable the validator.

This article is old, but it's information is still relevant: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside